# Проверка токена

Tags: swift

В приложение реализована авторизация через токен (пользователь присылает логин\пароль, сервер возвращает токен). Скажите, как можно проверять этот токен при входе в приложение? К примеру я сверну приложение, через 5 минут оно "перезагрузится" при открытии и мне надо, что бы в этот момент проверился токен.

Проверять токен при переходе на каждый экран - не очень хорошая идея, поскольку это банально будет бесить пользователей.

Comment: а нужно этот токен посылать в каждом запросе, который требует авторизированого доступа. А сервер может ответить 401 - нужна авторизация.

другое дело, если приложение было свернуто (а по факту - закрыто).  В этом случае нужно смотреть на специфику Вашего приложения. В одном случае можно просто показать, а проверку токена отложить. А в другом случае нужно жестко требовать проверку (например, если это работа с банковской картой).

Comment: А как сделать жёсткую проверку?

Comment: В ios можно отследить, что приложение свернули. В этот момент выставляйте флажок где нибудь в базе - нужна проверка. В тот момент, когда приложение развернут и флажок будет сброшен - делайте проверку и выставляйте флажок. Рядом с флажком я бы поставил текущее время проверки. И если даже флажок выствлен, но проверка была сильно давно (5 минут, 10), то все равно делать проверку.

А проверка - это просто спросить имя-пароль.

Comment: вам надо просто получить оповещение, когда приложение стало активным?